# How do I redirect all requests to a subfolder keeping the requested page slug intact?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all requests for pages.

Say for example

```
domain.com/contact
```

To

```
domain.com/subfolder/contact
```

I've checked out a lot of questions but I have some redirects setup in my htaccess file among other WP settings, could someone explain the best way for me to do this and keep the redirect I have?

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /sandyford/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Where is your Wordpress installation at? `subfolder` or root?

Comment: It's a multisite installation with the root wordpress site redirecting to one of the multisites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /sandyford/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:santry|sandyford)).+?)/?$ /sandyford/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: This will work for only `contact` page not all the pages. Thats what OP is looking for. Right?

Comment: No I need it for whatever the requested page was - so for example in my google results, the links listed under the site like /location or /prices need to redirect automatically to /sandyford/location and prices etc

Comment: will this redirect from another subdfolder though? I have two - /sandymount/ and /santry/ I only want the root domain to redirect to /sandymount/ but not any request for /santry/